# Hold'em: Why does K♠️7♠️ beat A♠️2♠️ more frequently than K♠️8♠️ does?

Tags: texas-hold-em, probability

According to [this site](http://www.cardplayer.com/poker-tools/odds-calculator/texas-holdem):

- K♠️7♠️ beats A♠️2♠️ 39.10% of the time (and ties 0.62%).
- K♠️8♠️ beats A♠️2♠️ 38.71% of the time (and ties 0.61%).

Why is this?

I expected the two probabilities to be the same. My reasoning was: For any community cards such that K♠️7♠️ beats A♠️2♠️, we can replace all community 7's with 8's, and find an equally likely set of community cards such that K♠️8♠️ beats A♠️2♠️.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

K7 steals one winner from A2

K7 wins 3456 and K8 does not

K8 does not *steal* 4567 as A2 does not have a piece of it